# How to print the value of the <element> specified into a macrodef?

Tags: java, ant, element, macrodef

Having a macrodef like

```
<macrodef name = "printSomething">
    <attribute name = "attribute1" />
    <element name = "args" optional="true"/>
    <sequential>
     <echo message = "attr is: @{attribute1} and the arguments are:"><args/></echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

which will be called like the example below

```
<printSomething attribute1="thisIsAttribute">
    <args>
        <arg value="element1"/>
        <arg value="element2"/>
    </args>
</printSomething>
```

How can I print elements element1 and element2 like below?

`attr is: thisIsAttribute and the arguments are: element1 element2`

This [aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318323/ant-macrodef-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-contents-of-an-element-parameter) doesn't help me. I DO NOT want to save the content of the xml into a property and print the property.

Comment: Please check if you can use `xmltask` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344295/how-to-parse-a-xml-by-ant

Comment: @Rao: It doesn't help me. I don't need to extract the elements each time I call <printSomething>. I need to put an echo into the macrodef so as to print the arguments passed when I call that printSomething task.